# datetime string parsing doesnt work with locale full name

Tags: python, datetime

Based on python datetime documentation the following string should be parsed using the following expression:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
d = 'December 10,2018'
dt.strptime('%B %d,%Y', d)
```

However this returns an error `time data '%B %d,%Y' does not match format 'December 10,2018'`
I live in the UK so I would expect the local name of the month to work in english..

ANy help appreciated

---

```
import locale
locale.getlocale()
```

returns `('en_GB', 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Order of arguments? `dt.strptime(d, '%B %d,%Y')`? It is very late in the UK, so maybe better continue in the morning? :)

Comment: Try this to exclude time part and as @alecxe mentioned the order of arguments are incorrect ```dt.strptime(d, '%B %d,%Y').date()```